# C# Using Forms Element in a new instance of a class

Tags: c#, windows, forms

First of all i am kinda new to C# but i understand enough to work mostly alone.

Now i have a problem that i have for some time with Windows Forms.
I'm trying to create a new Instance of a class called "FiestaService" which includes some variables (string, string, Label, Button).
I want to insert `label1` and `loginBtn` into `FiestaService Login` so i can call it inside `SCStatusCheck()`.
With the current code it only tells me

> a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field

at the `label = label1` and the same for `button = loginBtn`.

```
public partial class Main : Form 
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<FiestaService> FS = new List<FiestaService>();

    public FiestaService Login = new FiestaService() {
        serviceDataName = "Crestia_Login",
        serviceTextName = "Login",
        label = label1,    // this is the point where i am stuck with the label1
        button = loginBtn    // same
    };

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Login.serviceTextName;
        FS.Add(Login);
        //... here are some more of them
    }
    
    public void SCStatusCheck() // is called with a 2 seconds Timer inside the Main_Load method
    {
        foreach(var service in FS) {
            ServiceController SC = new ServiceController(service.serviceDataName);
            if (SC.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) {
                service.label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                service.button.Text = "Stop";
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FiestaService
{
    public string serviceDataName;
    public string serviceTextName;
    public Label label;
    public Button button;
}
```

The last thing i want to mention is that i did try it with

```
public static Main main = new Main();
```

and

```
public static FiestaService Login = new FiestaService() { ..., label = main.label1, button = main.loginBtn };
```

but after starting to debug it tells me

> The object reference was not set to an object instance.

That "is" working ..kinda.. and i can call them with the `Login FiestaService` but the `SCStatusCheck()` method can't change anything related to the Label/Button.

Thanks for everyone! If you see anything that i could do much better than i did feel free to correct me!

..and yes i have already read some posts. However, none of them led to a suitable solution.

Comment: It is not clear, what question are you asking? As a general comment, this does look like you are mixing the UI elements with the data where it is not necessary, it is better practice to keep all the UI components and your data separate. But I am not sure if that is what you are asking or not

Comment: I'm sorry it's a bit complicated. I'm trying to assign a label and a button to the class instance Login. As you can see at FiestaService login. It's easier for me to call Login.loginBtn instead of the button itself because i have more of those instances.

Comment: Are there different label+button for each instance of FiestaService? or is the same every time?

Comment: I have 12 instances of FiestaService and each of them has a label and button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem - the labels/buttons are created on this line:

```
InitializeComponent();
```

So you should defer creating the FiestaService instances until after this. Maybe like this:

```
public FiestaService Login;

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Login = new FiestaService() {
        serviceDataName = "Crestia_Login",
        serviceTextName = "Login",
        label = label1,    // this is the point where i am stuck with the label1
        button = loginBtn    // same
    };
}
```

The way you have it, when you do this:

```
new FiestaService() {
```

It happens before the labels are created, so all you do is set them to null

Also, think how you can separate the data from the UI. It is not good practice to mix it up like this, but if it works and you are just learning, don't worry too much.

Comment: I mean it works only if i put the FiestaService instances inside another method like Main or Main_Load. But then i can't call them from another method and that's what i need.

Comment: You can define Login as class variable to access it from everywhere like now but the new FS creating the instance needs to occur later.

Comment: Now that i see your edit it's such a simple solution but its working. Thank you!